# how to calculate the number of occurrences of a variable (digit) in a 2D vector in an optimized and fast way using STL?

Tags: c++, count, stl, 2d-vector

I have a 2D vector of Integer and want to count how many times certain value is repeated. For example:

I have `myvector` defined as:

```
std :: vector <std :: vector <int>> myVector {{{1, 2, 9, 4, 6},
                                       {8, 3, 5, 4, 8},
                                       {4, 1, 9, 1, 7},
                                       {5, 2, 7, 3, 4},
                                       {7, 4, 3, 5, 1};
```

My goal is to count number of elements where x = 4 for example, and the result return 5:
I tried:

```
int sum = 0;
for (auto i: myVector) {
     sum + = std :: count (i.begin (), i.end (), 4);
```

however, I need to run this type of method several times in a realtime application, but the for loop is time consuming, I am trying to minimize the execution time by using the functions of the STL, I have so tried:

```
   std :: count (myVector.begin (), myVector.end (), 4);
```

however, this syntax cannot work directly on a 2D vector.

anyone have a solution?

Comment: Use for ( const auto &i: myVector) {

Comment: You have to loop on all values anyway, done by algorithm or manually. So performance should be identical (if you avoid "typo" with extra copy).

Comment: I don't think you could get much faster than this. I don't know what you want to use this for, but you could consider using certain containers, like std::map or std::unordered_map to keep track of how many times a certain number is added to your matrix.

Comment: @S3gfault yes i will see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

> however, I need to run this type of method several times in a realtime application, but the for loop is time consuming, I am trying to minimize the execution time by using the functions of the STL, I have so tried:

If you want more than optimum execution time, don't even use a 2-D vector in the first place, you can just use a class that implements a 2-D view on top of a 1-D vector using some
common math.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
// ...

template <typename T>
class vector_2d_view : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
    size_type width_;
public:
    vector_2d_view(size_type const width) : width_(width) {};
    vector_2d_view(std::vector<T> vec, size_type const width) : std::vector<T>(std::move(vec)), width_(width) {}

    T& operator()(size_type const y, size_type const x) {
        auto const index = width_ * y + x;
        if (index >= this->size())
            this->resize(index + 1);
        return this->operator[](index);
    }
};
```

It uses a 1-D vector inside but provides a handy 2-D wrapper on top with `operator()`. Now you can access the elements like this:

```cpp
vector_2d_view<int> vec ({
    1, 2,
    3, 4
}, 2);

vec(0, 0); // Gives 1
vec(0, 1); // Gives 2
vec(1, 0); // Gives 3
vec(1, 1); // Gives 4
```

To count its elements, you can do it like this:

```cpp
// ...
const auto sum = std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 4);
// ...
```

Now, I have performed a benchmark to prove that the above is much faster than using the traditional `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you can check it out [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jddqvs7M6):

```
Time taken by 1st method (std::vector<std::vector<int>): 0.00027ms
5
Time taken by 2nd method (vector_2d_view<int>): 0.000105ms
5
```

This clearly shows that the 2nd method using `vector_2d_view<int>` finishes counting faster than the 1st method.

> ***P.S.:*** The above times may differ during each iteration but even after doing it a lot of times I still got similar results where the time taken by 2nd was less than the time taken by 1st.